# Реализация FAT32

Tags: c, fat32

Пытаюсь найти реализацию fat32 на Cи обеспечивающую выполнение следующих требований:

- возможность компиляции как на x86, так и на ARM (например под Android);
- дружелюбный API;
- "образ диска" при монтировании не должен загружаться в память весь и сразу;

Покопался на Github, но ничего подходящего не смог найти. Прошу помощи у сообщества.

Comment: Поройтесь в исходниках линукса, там есть, и они достаточно хорошие.

Comment: К сожалению я не могу использовать GPL лицензии.

Comment: Покопайтесь в исходниках FreeBSD.

Comment: **я не могу использовать GPL лицензии** - использовать могут ВСЕ. В том числе - для создания НЕ GPL (коммерческих) приложений.

Comment: @Sergey а вы не путаете с LGPL?

Comment: Принципиальной разницы нет.  Они в деталях различаются, что-то про библиотеки там говорится. Короче, вот цитата (официальный перевод): "GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE 
Версия 2, июнь 1991г. ... если вы распространяете экземпляры такого программного обеспечения за плату или бесплатно, вы обязаны передать новым обладателям все права в том же объеме, в каком они принадлежат вам...". Проще говоря, если Ваша программа, которую  Вы ПРОДАЁТЕ использует СВОБОДНУЮ библиотеку ibzzz.so, то Вы обязаны информировать  покупателя о лицензии библиотеки libzzz.so. Всё !  Ну, почитайте сами, для 100% уверенности.

Comment: @Sergey, о, поведайте сразу списком, в чём вы не очень хорошо ориентируетесь ;)